# type hinting array with 2 entries / phpdoc for array

Tags: php, php-7, phpdoc

say i have this

```
function foo(){
   return [1, 'bippo'];

}
```

how can I write phpdoc that it creates automatically on autocomplete something like this

```
list($x, $y) = foo();
```

Comment: I think the answer from @Jelmergu should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

As stated in the [phpDocumentor: Defining a 'Type' section Array](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays) you can specify an array containing multiple types as `@return (int|string)[]`, which means that the return type of this function is an array that can contain elements which are either of type `int` or `string`

Comment: in case you know, is it possible to return specific objects? E.g. I mean type hint something like this `[int => MyCoolObj]` indicating that the array consists out of keys of type int, the the values of type `MyCoolObj`

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.

Comment: Link not dead anymore

Comment: OP asks about hinting a tuple. Answers shows how to hint an array whose element type is a union. Completely unrelated.

Comment: This is a helpful answer for certain PHPDoc array typehints, but does not help specify the types within a tuple